# mp4-h264 video decoding with Media Foundation

Tags: video, decode, h.264, mp4, ms-media-foundation

I'm testing how to integrate libavcodec (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libavcodec) using MS Media Foundation SDK, in order to decode h264-lossless format video to YUV/RGB raw data

I have 2 question:

1. I have had issues to load mp4 video encoded with h264/AVC (in regular, not lossless format) into MFPlayer (compiled in VS2010 from MF SDK examples), the error code was: bad byte stream. 
   The same error occurred, when I tried to load the same video as  stream (source reader code taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd389281%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or as session using trans-codding  example. 
   May be anyone may share experience how to use Media Foundation to load mp4-h264 video.
2. I should to integrate third-party codec to Media Foundation based decoding.
   According to MSDN, Media Foundation has some support to third-party codecs, however I didn't find example that does decoding using third-party codec.
   May be someone did that ? or may reference to usable example how to do that.

Thanks in advance,
Ze'ev

Comment: Hi Ze'ev, I'm trying something similar but am struggling to get the decoder work on "SetInputType". Could you help me on this. Please check my question on: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/mediafoundationdevelopment/thread/17d0925b-c716-4ebb-9450-71a2f54a5912

Comment: Intel has a sample decoder MFT in their current Media SDK (which is free for download). you might give it a try

Answer (score 0):

> (2) I should to integrate third-party codec to Media Foundation based decoding. According to MSDN, Media Foundation has some support to third-party codecs, however I didn't find example that does decoding using third-party codec. May be someone did that ? or may reference to usable example how to do that.

This is possible. Basically, it involves writing a [Media Foundation Transform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for the third party decoder. Look into your SDK installation directory. Go to `Microsoft SDKs -> v7.0 -> Samples -> Multimedia -> Mediafoundation -> Decoder`. It contains a sample MPEG1 decoder MFT. What you need to do is appropriately inherit `IMFTransform` interface and implement its methods. For example, a media client will call `ProcessInput()` method to provide your decoder MFT with media samples. Similarly it will call `ProcessOutput()` to get the decoded output. In short, MFT acts as a wrapper for the third party decoder.